# Checking form for duplicate values in JavaScript, issue with hidden nulls?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a function to test for duplicate values in my form. My form contains logic where if a checkbox is not checked, certain input fields are hidden from a user with style="display:none".

The issue I am having is that I think my function to test duplicate values is taking the hidden fields into consideration and since the hidden fields are all null, it thinks they are duplicate values.

I tried using an if statement to rule out null values but not having any luck. Any advice? Thanks.

Here is my function:

```
            function valid(test) {
            for (i = 0; i < test.elements.length; i++) {
                if (test.elements[i].type == "number" && test.elements[i].value != null) {
                    var text1 = test.elements[i].value;
                    for (j = i + 1; j < test.elements.length; j++) {
                        if (test.elements[j].type == "number" && test.elements[j].value != null) {
                            var text2 = test.elements[j].value;
                            if (text1 == text2) {
                                alert("Please remove any duplicate values.")
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty value of an input is an empty string and not null. So it should be:

```
&& test.elements[i].value != ''
```